# How to create a custom function to compare rgb values in scss file

Tags: sass

I have two color hashes, I wanted to check if they are equal by calculating RGB values in scss file.

```
@function are_equal($color1, $color2) {
    $red: red($color1) == red($color2);
    $green: green($color1) == green($color2);
    $blue: blue($color1) == blue($color2);
    @return $red and $green and $blue;
}
```

Calling this function like

```
@if are_equal(#12AC1FF, #12AC1F)
```

I am getting error: `Could not resolve the variable "$color1" within "are_equal($color1, $color2)"`

Comment: `#12AC1FF` is not a valid color code for sass color functions.